# macOS sysadminctl -adduser: execute as root?

Tags: macos, script

The goal is a configuration-script, runs immediate after a clean install. It should create some users, f. e. an local administrator and a user - account and manage some basic configurations.

When I create a package for that, scripts inside that will be executed as root by default. This is changeable, but to change that is very complicated.

Somewhere I read, that one Should / must not execute systemctl -adduser as root.

Is this true?
Are there workarounds for my needs?

PS: Thanx to ls07 > Changed the type-error

Comment: Have you tried this? What was the result?

Comment: Do you mean `sysadminctl`?

Comment: Thank you lx07. Changed that!